# WSO2 ESB authentication property not initialized

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm evaluating WSO2 ESB 4.8 and my goal is to mushup two existing soap services and offer them via WSO2 ESB Rest API.

Basically what I need to do is ask authorizations etc. from the first service (using callout mediator for blocking call) and if everything is OK then continue to call the seconds service and prepare response to the client. However seems that ESB is some how caching the properties. I'm using boolean property "isAuthenticated" which is set after callout mediator which is set based on the xpath query of the response. First if I use invalid credentials, isAuthenticated value keeps false and Filter -mediator drops the request, which is expected. Now if I use valid credentials, isAutenticated is true and it continues to second service which is OK but after that if I set invalid credentials again it keeps calling the second service and isAuthenticated property is set true. I've tried to remove isAuthenticated property in begin of Sequence but no help. If I re-deploy the API, it initializes the state.

Anyone can help ?

Thanks,
Kari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, got this solved. The problem is not actually related to ESB but endpoint service which was reusing the old session cookie for new connection and therefore it skipped checking the new credentials.